# UIScreen.mainscreen.bounds returning wrong width&height

Tags: swift

I am making a game in Swift using SpriteKit, however I am having some difficulty placing a sprite in the centre of the screen.

Here is how I get the dimensions:

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
```

I have also tried this:

```
screenWidth = self.frame.width
```

but the both return the same value of 768x1024 (portrait).

Is there an alternative way of getting screen dimensions, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra `.size` in there.

So it'd be

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
```

Calling `mainScreen().bounds` gives you a [CGRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGRect), which you have to get the [size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGSize) of to grab the height and width (see the [documentation for `UIScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/) and [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds) in particular).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height returns the same value, and so does UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.width

Comment: @CalebCheng Is the value that it's returning incorrect? What value are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, the value is correct (2048x1536 / 2).... still can't get a sprite to position correctly in the centre. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @CalebCheng No problem; glad I could help. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html) looks like it could help you with centering a little bit since they talk about how to position and anchor sprites onscreen.

Comment: ahaha I'm an idiot. Wasn't adding the width of the sprite. Thanks for your help man :D

Comment: @CalebCheng No problem; good luck with your project!